# Are there official button images for the xbox controller that I can get for free?

Tags: art, pc, xbox-controller

If you want to support xbox controllers, it is always wise to use the native images that the controller uses. Can one obtain those from Microsoft without being a registered, aka paying developer?

Comment: what about getting images from the xbox itself is it like possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get official Microsoft logos here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/ImageGallery/logos/logoguidelines.aspx (You have to agree to their terms in order to get to the logo part).

Here you might get some publicly available assets: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/imagegallery/products/default.aspx (Well, there isn't a top-down shot of X-Box controller, but maybe you can get away with Limited Edition one)

So, to directly answer your question - **no**, there are not publicly available official images to be used for keymapping hints.

Last, but not least, you can always try to look up contacts of the company, and send them an email. You're not asking for a free X-Box, Kinect, TV and sofa - it's only an image.

I, personally, am not a developer of X-Box games or anything related to X-Box, but maybe you get some illustrations with the [developer kit](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US)?

Comment: Actually, it is probably more difficult to get them to allow you to use an image than to get an X-Box, Kinect, TV and sofa. Their image is part of their corporate image, and including it in any product may imply that MS is endorsing your product. This is actually a legal question, and you should seek advice from a qualified legal practitioner.

Comment: To add to your answer, I found those on a microsoft site: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/controller_buttons They are not from Microsoft, but freely available under Creative Commons Attribution 3.0

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 4):

There is an unofficial but extremely complete set of controller button images for several platforms here:

http://opengameart.org/content/free-keyboard-and-controllers-prompts-pack

Answer (score 0):

These are not official, but are good...

http://sinnix.net/downloads/

Comment: Your link is broken.